# SQL Server 2008 R2 - count total from a number range

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Can i get a suggestion on how the script is written for the below case

need to count # of members from  a table 
and assign $1.00 for the  members for the first 20 members( 1-20),
    aSSIGN $1.10 for the  members from 21-30,
    aSSIGN $1.20 for the  members from 31-40,
and if we have 50 members for the 1st case (assign $1.00 for the  members from 1-20,
)get total $50*1
and if we have 70 members for the 2st case (aSSIGN $1.10 for the  members from 21-30,
)get total $70*1.10
and if we have 90 members for the 2st case (aSSIGN $1.20 for the  members from 31-40,
)get total $00*1.20

Answer (score 0):

IF you can provide desired out put in tabler form, it is easy to understand and any body can provide a solution for it....

Now I am suggesting this query for what I understand....

```
select ROW_NUMBER () over (order by Member) ID
,Member
,case 
when ID between 1 and 20 then 1.00
when ID between 21 and 30 then 1.10
when ID between 31 and 40 then 1.20
--when ID between 41 and 50 then $1.30  --Rest cases are not clear..
End Amount
from
(
        select ROW_NUMBER () over (order by UID_PatientAccountNumber) ID
,UID_PatientAccountNumber from 
test
)A
```

try this code if you get partial result up <= 40 members case then provide the rest cases desired out put ill try to give solution for thet according to my knowledge (It may not be a performence based solutions).